# On using "gone down"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, sentence-meaning, sentence-structure

Is this a correct use for `gone down`?

> Many websites could have gone down during the years.

What I want to say, is the websites do not exist any more. I want to use `gone down`, but not sure if it is correct here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Gone down** would mean that the people maintaining the website were no longer able to keep maintaining it and it eventually went offline. This is more frequently used for saying that a website **has gone down** due to technical issues or even hacking.

> Google has **gone down** due to technical issues in the servers.

You could've also said that "many websites have been **taken down** over the years", that would mean that maybe the government or some higher power took these websites from the web because of criminal activity or misuse of information.

> MegaUpload has been **taken down** by the government after allegedly uploading illegal content to their servers.

It all depends on your context, but there, are two expressions you could use.

Comment: Now, it's fine.